# Kaggle: Dealing with extra unlabelled test data in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, kaggle

I'm doing a kaggle competition and I've got extra test data that I don't have labels for.

I have a train.txt file which has the format

```
train/0.jpg 5
train/1.jpg 1
train/2.jpg 10
train/3.jpg 2
train/4.jpg 22
train/5.jpg 3
etc...
```

So image 0.jpg is of class 5 for example.

This continues to train/10259.jpg

I then assign these labels to my train data and then my test data, so they become.

```
0.jpg -> 5.0.jpg
2.jpg -> 10.2.jpg
```

10259 is the size of my train dataset. Therefore, I have all the labels the training set.

I then do the same with the /test folder. However, I've got more test images than train, therefore there are some test images that I don't have labels for.

I'm using Keras ImageDataGenerator() and I've sorted my classes into folders like so:

[image: folder structure]

In my test dataset, because I don't have labels for some of the data. It's similar to the image above, but there are images that haven't been put into their class folders.

I'm unsure what to do with this unlabelled test data. Will it be fine leaving them as they are? Or should I split them into another set?

Comment: In training sets, sometimes they use "Label propagation" for labeling unlabeled data. But in test data i am not sure if it is the correct approach

Comment: @MeBottleOScrumpy I'm going to seach around for some more clarity. But it feels like it should be split into validation data. But not sure if it'll be useful as they'll be unlabelled.

Comment: i think training data should be split to validation + training. Both of them must be labeled since validation data has influence in training of the network and it's hyperparameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you label the data yourself (by hand) or have another (superior) model at hand, there is not much you can do with the unlabeled "test" data.

The idea of test data is to compare the predicted results with the true labels - if you don't have them, you should discard the data from the test set.

Answer (score 0):

data that is not labelled is useless when doing classification. Doesn't matter if it is in the train, test or validation data sets.